# Differentiability at point $0$

Tags: analysis

Let $f:R^n\to R^m$ satisfies $||f(x)||\leq ||x||^2$ for all $x\in R^n$ then show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

I need to use definition of differentiability for higher dimensions. So i have to check does there exist $L:R^n\to R^m$ linear transformation such that the limit is $0$. I want to ask that Can i choose $L$ directly $0$??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $L  = 0 \colon \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$ is a linear transformation, and you are correct in saying that $0$ is the derivative of $f$ at $x=0$.

Comment: by hypothesis $f(0)=0$ clearly and $||f(0+h)-f(0)-L(h)||/||h||$ tends to $0$ as $h\to 0$ if $L(h)=0$ then it is obvious that limit is $0$

Comment: @JamalGadirov Correct.